# Rename reserved IP Address in GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is it possible to rename an existing reserved IP address without having to release it?

Its just to aid administration within a project where the reserved IP name doesn't match the registered DNS name of the instance that its attached to

Comment: No, I have not found any way of doing this either.

Comment: I didnt find a feature request for it on https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list but for some reason my account doesn't have permission to create 1 either on that site

Comment: I have created a feature request on your behalf: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=72

Comment: Thanks for that. I couldn't have said it better myself

Comment: Another anomaly they have, is in the web console, when you reserve a new static ip, you can name it, but also specify a description. However I do not see anywhere that this description is used afterwards. On gcutil reserveinstance there is no description option.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the latest GCE API](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/addresses), it is not possible to rename an address object.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if you rename it whilst moving it to a different Project and move it back again
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/move-ip-address-different-project

---

First move the IP address to another GCP project (just create a temporary project if you don't have more than one already):

```bash
gcloud compute addresses move OLD_IP_NAME_HERE --project=PROJECT_ID --target-project=TEMP_PROJECT_ID --global
```

Then move the IP address back, setting a new name at the same time:

```bash
gcloud compute addresses move OLD_IP_NAME_HERE --new-name=NEW_IP_NAME_HERE --project=TEMP_PROJECT_ID --target-project=PROJECT_ID --global
```

Comment: This is the answer as long as the IP isn't in active use with traffic coming to it. Instructions added to the post